# Hexadecimal confusion

Tags: python

Python 2.7.2

```
>>binascii.unhexlify("FFFFFFFFFFFF")

'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

What format is in the second line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to actually accomplish ... but thats a string ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What format is in the second line?

It's a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

Answer (score 0):

unhexlify takes your string of 12 *hexadecimal* characters and creates a string of 6 bytes

Since the 6 bytes are non-printable in this case, they are shown as '\xff'

another way to construct the bytes would be

```
chr(0xff) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xff)
```

Note that for hexadecimal the case is not significant 'f'=='F'